# How do I insert multiple object instances into array?

Tags: java, arrays, object

I tried to insert 5 object instances into an array but im not sure im doing it right. Can someone tell me what am I missing?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Body[] bodiesArr = new Body[5];

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        double x = StdIn.readDouble();
        double y = StdIn.readDouble();
        String pic = StdIn.readString();
        Body body = new Body(x, y, pic);
        bodiesArr[i] = body;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the error that you are receiving?

Comment: Is missing semicolon after `bodiesArr[i] = body` a typo?

Comment: 1. Can you add a tag for the programming language 2. What is the problem? Do you get an error, or are the values not present?

Comment: @Aycan Yaşıt Thanks! can't believe I did not see it..

Comment: *im not sure im doing it right*: what makes you feel that? Have you compiled that code? Have you run it? Have you printed the contents of the array to see what it contains? Have you had any error? If so, what is the message?

Comment: Your problem was a semicolon? How did the compiler not tell you about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to use System.in instead of StdIn, example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Body[] bodiesArr = new Body[5];
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        double x = sc.nextDouble();
        double y = sc.nextDouble();
        String pic = sc.nextLine();
        Body body = new Body(x, y, pic);
        bodiesArr[i] = body;
    }

}
```